# How to add more than one WHERE statements in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Can anyone give me some examples to make query which has more than one WHERE statements please?

I have the following query and I want to add WHERE privacy = 'public'

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(eventDate,'%d') AS 
day,eventContent,eventTitle,id FROM eventcal WHERE eventDate BETWEEN 
'$current_year/$current_month/01' AND '$current_year/$current_month
/$total_days_of_current_month'");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll need to explain better what you want... otherwise the easy obvious answer is exactly that... obvious! ;)

Answer (score 3):

`[..] WHERE privacy = 'public' AND (eventDate BETWEEN [..] )` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
AND privacy = 'public'
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about MySql specifically, but it looks like you just need another AND statement:

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(eventDate,'%d') AS
day,eventContent,eventTitle,id FROM eventcal WHERE
eventDate BETWEEN  '$current_year/$current_month/01'
AND '$current_year/$current_month/$total_days_of_current_month'
**AND privacy='public'**");

Answer (score 1):

Change the WHERE to AND:

```
AND privacy = 'public'
```

In full, and made more readable:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(eventDate,'%d') AS day,
       eventContent,
       eventTitle,
       id
FROM   eventcal
WHERE  eventDate BETWEEN '$current_year/$current_month/01'
                     AND '$current_year/$current_month/$total_days_of_current_month'
AND    privacy = 'public'
```